# Reporting results from a GLMER

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, reporting

I have conducted a generalized linear mixed model (GLMM). For the output, see below. Normally (when reporting results from an ANOVA), I write something like this: $F(1, 116) = 6.09$, $p = .015$, $η2 = .04$.  But which statistical parameters (e.g. $\beta$, ...) do I use when reporting the results below (according to APA)?

````
   747.5    788.7   -364.7    729.5      711 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.4527 -0.4184  0.2273  0.4934  2.0564 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 3.006    1.734   
Number of obs: 720, groups:  id, 120

Fixed effects:
                                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                     -9.985e-01  5.763e-01  -1.733   0.0832 .  
Risikodarstellung                1.351e+00  7.763e-01   1.740   0.0819 .  
Icon                            -7.898e-01  7.961e-01  -0.992   0.3211    
Position                        -8.368e-07  1.183e-01   0.000   1.0000    
Risikodarstellung:Icon          -9.109e-02  1.141e+00  -0.080   0.9364    
Risikodarstellung:Position       3.297e-01  1.659e-01   1.987   0.0469 *  
Icon:Position                    7.937e-01  1.822e-01   4.357 1.32e-05 ***
Risikodarstellung:Icon:Position -4.527e-01  2.673e-01  -1.694   0.0903 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Rskdrs Icon   Positn Rskd:I Rskd:P Icn:Ps
Rskdrstllng -0.746                                          
Icon        -0.712  0.529                                   
Position    -0.718  0.533  0.520                            
Rskdrstll:I  0.502 -0.675 -0.698 -0.363                     
Rskdrstll:P  0.502 -0.700 -0.371 -0.713  0.480              
Icon:Positn  0.446 -0.325 -0.719 -0.649  0.495  0.477       
Rskdrst:I:P -0.312  0.435  0.490  0.443 -0.719 -0.620 -0.670 ```



I
````

Comment: I don't know that there's a specific APA guideline for mixed models ... https://www.scribbr.com/apa-style/numbers-and-statistics/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ben noted in the comments, there are no APA standards for reporting mixed models. However, there are certainly a good number of important parts about your analysis that should be included if this is for a published manuscript. A useful paper on this subject is Meteyard and Davies, 2020, which notes on Page 16 what you should include:

- Software and version used.
- What data cleaning/wrangling was involved and whether or not your data meets the assumptions of mixed models.
- Fixed and random effects are explicitly noted with important theoretical underpinnings noted for how the model was constructed.
- Sample size in terms of units of observations (50 subjects x 10 items = 500 observations for crossed effects models).
- Whatever model comparison was employed and the metrics that go with that (such as AIC/BIC).
- Convergence issues and how they were handled.
- The model equation and output (normally reported in a table), which includes pretty much everything it spits out (point estimates, standard errors, etc) as well as model fit metrics (pseudo R2 values for example).
- If possible, the data and code itself.

Here is an example from an article which includes a good number of these things but not all of them. They include the fixed effects on the top and the random effects on the bottom, along with the beta coefficients, the standard errors, and the t-values that go with them (I only include part of it here because its very long:

[image]

And another example here, where you can see they included the actual equations, R2 values, and p values:

[image]

Reporting of these models varies a lot. More is always better, so include as much as possible and try to follow the guides I have cited here.

##### Citations

*Best Practice Guides*

- Brown, V. A. (2021). An introduction to linear mixed-effects modeling in R. Advances in Methods and Practices in Psychological Science, 4(1), 1–19. https://doi.org/10.1177/2515245920960351
- Harrison, X. A., Donaldson, L., Correa-Cano, M. E., Evans, J., Fisher, D. N., Goodwin, C. E. D., Robinson, B. S., Hodgson, D. J., & Inger, R. (2018). A brief introduction to mixed effects modelling and multi-model inference in ecology. PeerJ, 6, e4794. https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.4794
- Meteyard, L., & Davies, R. A. I. (2020). Best practice guidance for linear mixed-effects models in psychological science. Journal of Memory and Language, 112, 104092. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jml.2020.104092

*Example Studies*

- Al-Dajani, N., & Czyz, E. K. (2022). Suicidal desire in adolescents: An examination of the interpersonal psychological theory using daily diaries. Journal of Clinical Child & Adolescent Psychology. https://doi.org/10.1080/15374416.2022.2051525
- Wang, L., Wang, J., Liu, D., & Lin, D. (2021). The role of metalinguistic awareness and character properties in early Chinese reading. Journal of Experimental Child Psychology, 210, 105185. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jecp.2021.105185

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: One further question: If I have to report an effect size, which would you choose?

Comment: You can consider [pseudo R2 values for the model itself](https://doi.org/10.1098/rsif.2017.0213)

Comment: And [part R2](https://peerj.com/articles/11414) for the predictors.

Comment: Okay thanks. So would it look like this? ß = ___ , p = _____, part R2 = _____ (I know, that these are not the correct characters, but to get an idea). Or do I need a t-value instead of ß (ß stands for the estimates in my output I guess). Alternatively, I thought about reporting it like this: ß, p, Cohens D (ß/SE => which are both in my output)...

Comment: Another question regarding this: How can I report descriptive data? According to my teacher, I have to report things like this (example for ANOVA): The participants in the conditions ARR (M = 4.37, SD = 1.73) and ARR-Icon (M = 4.48, SD = 1.66) achieved a significantly higher total score compared to the individuals in the conditions RRR (M = 2.14, SD = 2.17) and RRR-Icon (M = 3.87, SD = 1.54), F(1, 116) = 20.23, p < .001, η2 = .14.    But I don't know how to apply this to my mixed model output.

Comment: The guides go over that to a degree. Minimum would be some general descriptives about participants but can be defined in any way that its useful to add.